# CSS selector where 2 (both) conditions are met

Tags: css

I am trying to craft a CSS selector that would select 1 element if two different conditions are true.

I have an unknown number of `<div>`'s  with the class name `grid-item` that display in 4 columns. I want to select the last element, but only if the last element is the first in its own row `(4n+5)`.

So, I want to select the element where both of these selectors are true:

```
.grid-item:last-child
.grid-item:nth-child(4n+5)
```

Comment: `.grid-item:nth-child(4n+5):last-child` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - seems so obvious